# Python closure + global strangeness

Tags: python

I expected this little snippet to print *"Why doesn't this work?"*  Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work as I expect?  I'm using Python 2.6, if this matters.

```
class WhyDoesntThisWork(object):
  def outer(self):
    acc = ''
    def inner(msg):
      global acc
      acc = acc + msg
    inner("Why doesn't")
    inner(" this work?")
    print acc
WhyDoesntThisWork().outer()
```

- If I include the `global` statement I get a `NameError: global name 'acc' is not defined`
  .
- If I don't include the `global` statement I get a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'acc' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: `global` does not work with closures. You'd need `nonlocal` from python 3 instead.

Comment: Use a mutable instead (no global keyword); `acc = []`, `acc.append`, etc.

Comment: Alright, so using a mutable (`acc = []`) works.  Can you explain why that matters... just for trivia later on?

Comment: I suspect this Q. is a dupe; but I am out of time right now to find it for you.

Comment: Why it matters: because `acc.append(msg)` does not need to point `acc` to a different object as `acc = acc + msg` does.

Comment: Mutable/Immutable matters because closures in Python are read-only.  Once `acc` has been closed upon, its value cannot be changed.  However, if you use a mutable object (such as a list or dict, where the value in this case should be considered as the object reference) you are free to change the contents.

Comment: Closures are not read-only in Python 3, where `nonlocal` can be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know why so many comments above contain the correct answer and no one dared to write an actual answer, so I'll do it hereby.

```
class ThisWorksNow(object):
  def outer(self):
    acc = []
    def inner(msg):
      acc.append(msg)
    inner("Why doesn't")
    inner(" this work?")
    print "".join(acc)
ThisWorksNow().outer()
```

What is the difference?

Assigning a name to an object which is in the closure doesn't work in Python 2.x, because the Py3 keyword `nonlocal` is missing, so we have to find a workaround.

If we have to keep the name-to-object-binding constant, we have to change something else. In this case, it is the object, to which we add the content to be added.

The `print` line is not very elegant; maybe an object which prints its contents concatenated might be more suitable.

```
class StringBuilder(list): # class name stolen from Java
    def __str__(self):
        """this makes the object printable in a way which represents the concatenated string"""
        return "".join(self)
    @property
    def string(self):
        """this gives us a property which represents the concatenated string"""
        return "".join(self)
 # use whatever suits you better, one or both
```

With this, we can do that:

```
class ThisWorksNow(object):
  def outer(self):
    acc = StringBuilder()
    def inner(msg):
      acc.append(msg)
    inner("Why doesn't")
    inner(" this work?")
    print acc
    print acc.string # depending on what you take above
ThisWorksNow().outer()
```

Edit (append): Why does `global` not work?

We could achieve this with `global` as well, with 2 downsides.

1. `acc` would have to be made global on both places we use it

   ```
   class WhyDoesntThisWork(object):
     def outer(self):
       global acc
       acc = ''
       def inner(msg):
         global acc
         acc = acc + msg
   ```

   Hereby we "lift" both `acc` occurrences to "`global`" level.
2. `acc` could be modified from outside.

   If we do `global acc` somewhere else, or we use `acc` on module level, our process can be tampered with. This should be avoided.

Comment: Please clarify.  Rather than just perceiving that the `nonlocal` keyword would allow this to work, please explain the mechanics of what happens when using the `global` keyword in that place.  Is the `global` keyword ignored by the interpreter, etc.

Comment: I think I see.  This implies that the `global` keyword really only applies to variables defined at the module level; and that using `global` within a closure isn't a problem in itself, as some commenters have claimed.

Comment: It is not a big problem, but it is unclean, as it pollutes the module level name space and might lead to collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper closure class like below to explicitly mark the variable as closure. Not sure if such a utility already exist.

```
class closure:
    def __init__(self, val = None):
        self.val = val
    def __call__(self, val = None):
      if val:
        self.val = val
      return self.val
class WhyDoesntThisWork(object):
  def outer(self):
    acc = closure('')
    def inner(msg):
      acc(acc() + msg)
    inner("Why doesn't")
    inner(" this work?")
    print acc
WhyDoesntThisWork().outer()
```